# Centre Align Search Box - SharePoint 2013

Tags: search, design

On my SharePoint site I am tryint to centre-align a search box I have inserted into the Content - any idea on how this is done?

[image]

Comment: Take a look at how SharePoint Search Center landing page is designed. That should help.